# a thread python with 'while' got another thread never start

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm trying to adding a number once 1 second and monitor the result every 3 seconds for 2 times. I tried to use threading in python but as a thread is running, the other never start.

```
import threading, time

a = 0
def a1():
    print('adding')
    global a
    while a < 1000:
        a+=1
        print('a from a1', a)
        time.sleep(1)


def showprogress():
    global a
    print(a)
    time.sleep(3)
    print(a)
    time.sleep(3)
    print(a)

t1 = threading.Thread(target=a1())
t2 = threading.Thread(target=showprogress())
t1.start()
t2.start()
```

below is the output

```
adding
a from a1 1
a from a1 2
a from a1 3
a from a1 4
a from a1 5
a from a1 6
a from a1 7
a from a1 8
```

showprogress function never get executed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work. The reason why yours doesnt is because you are passing the function, `a1()` into the target. `target` takes in a callable object so by passing in the entire function inside, what you are actually doing is passing in the return value, which is `None` in this case. `showprogress()` will then execute after `a()` which will also pass in `None` into the parameter.

If you would like to pass arguments into your function, what you can do is

`t1 = threading.Thread(target=a1 ,args=(4,0.25))` (that is if your function takes in arguments.)

```
import threading, time

a = 0
def a1():
    print('adding')
    global a
    while a < 1000:
        a+=1
        print('a from a1', a)
        time.sleep(1)


def showprogress():
    global a
    print(a)
    time.sleep(3)
    print(a)
    time.sleep(3)
    print(a)

t1 = threading.Thread(target=a1)
t2 = threading.Thread(target=showprogress)
t1.start()
t2.start()
t1.join()
t2.join()
```

Comment: @EdelWang hi, your mistake is not the `.join()` it is passing in the parameter of `a1()` instead of `a1`. `.join()` basically means that the thread will join back to the main thread after its done so that it exits properly.

Comment: @EdelWang if you think that this solves your problem, you can accept this as an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).